# Having an issue with shared validation schemas in my Fastify app

Tags: node.js, fastify, ajv

In my app initialization, I define two shared schemas:

```
    fastify.addSchema({
        $id: 'auth',
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            Authorization: { type: 'string' },
        },
        required: ['Authorization'],
    })

    fastify.addSchema({
        $id: 'payload',
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            data: { type: 'object' },
            rid: { type: 'string' },
        },
    })
```

In my controller, I attempt to reference the shared schemas:

```
const schema = {
    headers: { $ref: 'auth#' },
    response: {
        200: {
            $merge: {
                source: { $ref: 'payload#/properties/data' },
                with: {
                    properties: {
                        antivirus: { type: 'string' },
                        db: { type: 'string' },
                        started: { type: 'number' },
                        deployVersion: { type: 'string' },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

But this does not work for the `auth#` schema. My request causes a validation error `must have required property 'Authorization'`

However, if I replace the reference to the shared schema `auth#` with the schema json, then it works as expected.

```
const schema = {
    headers: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
            Authorization: { type: 'string' },
        },
        required: ['Authorization'],
    },
    response: {
        200: {
            $merge: {
                source: { $ref: 'payload#/properties/data' },
                with: {
                    properties: {
                        antivirus: { type: 'string' },
                        db: { type: 'string' },
                        started: { type: 'number' },
                        deployVersion: { type: 'string' },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using the default serializer? Because `$merge` is not supported by fast-json-stringify. Regarding the header schema - Isn't `must have required property 'Authorization'` a valid error since the schema says that the `Authorization` header is required?

Comment: I am initializing fastify to use that ajv plugin the same as shown in their docs here: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/#ajv-plugins

I am sending an Authorization header with my postman request, the validation works correctly when I don't reference the shared schema and just copy/paste the schema object

Comment: I set up a global error handler to get a peek at what it's seeing in the request, and it appears the `Authorization` header is being sent as lowercase `authorization` ... whoops. I still don't quite understand why it would work when I replaced the shared `auth#` schema with the schema json. Logging the request headers from the controller in this case still shows a lowercase 'authorization' header